# Ordenar array por chave, sendo uma string

Tags: php, array, classificação

Possuo um array aleatório contendo em suas chaves, uma sequência alfanumérica. Utilizando a função [ksort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ksort.php), obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
array(22) {
  ["A1"]=>
  string(2) "A1"
  ["A10"]=>
  string(3) "A10"
  ["A11"]=>
  string(3) "A11"
  ["A12"]=>
  string(3) "A12"
  ["A2"]=>
  string(2) "A2"
  ["A4"]=>
  string(2) "A4"
  ["A5"]=>
  string(2) "A5"
}
```

Porém a ordenação deve dar prioridade a ordem numérica das chaves. O resultado esperado é:

```
array(22) {
  ["A1"]=>
  string(2) "A1"
  ["A2"]=>
  string(3) "A2"
  ["A4"]=>
  string(2) "A4"
  ["A5"]=>
  string(2) "A5"
  ["A10"]=>
  string(2) "A10"
  ["A11"]=>
  string(3) "A11"
  ["A12"]=>
  string(3) "A12"
}
```

Comment: A ordenação feita pelo ksort está correta, porque a sua chave é texto e não número ...

Comment: O que você quer seria basicamente separar a `string` do numero ordenando primeiramente pela string a apos pelo numero, correto?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert ele quer ordernar pelo número olha o segundo exemplo que é a saída

Comment: Os dois estão corretos. Eu preciso ordenar tanto pela letra como por número como exemplifiquei o resultado esperado.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade mas qual a prioridade a letra ou o numero?

Comment: A letra, depois o número. A1 A2 A13 B2 B3 B10 etc...

Comment: O `A`  é fixo? se sim pode cortar ele fora e adicioanar depois.

Comment: O meu exemplo foi apenas uma pequena demonstração, @rray. O array pode conter valores de A1-A99 até Z1-Z99.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa ordenar as chaves utilizando o algoritmo de ordenação natural. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
$dados = [
    'A1'=> 'A1',
    'A10'=> 'A10',
    'A11'=> 'A11',
    'A12'=> 'A12',
    'A2'=> 'A2',
    'A4'=> 'A4',
    'A5'=> 'A5',
];

uksort($dados, 'strnatcmp');
var_dump($dados);
?>
```

Comment: Putz! Nunca tinha visto essa função `strnatcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Codigo

```
$sort = array(
    "A1"    =>  "A1",
    "A10"   =>  "A10",
    "A11"   =>  "A11",
    "A12"   =>  "A12",
    "A2"    =>  "A2",
    "A4"    =>  "A4",
    "A5"    =>  "A5",
    "C12"   =>  "C12",
    "C1"    =>  "C1",
    "B7"    =>  "B7",
    "C52"   =>  "C52",
    "C5"    =>  "C5",
    "B12"   =>  "B12",
);
ksort($sort); // Ordena o array por string

$sortNumber = array();
foreach ($sort as $key => $value){       // quebra o array em bidimencional separando letras de numeros
    $string = preg_replace('~[^a-z]~i', '', $key);
    $number = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $key);

    $sortNumber[$string][$number] = $value;
}

$newArray = array(); 
foreach ($sortNumber as $letter => $options) {  
    ksort($options); // ordena a parte numerica
    foreach ($options as $number => $value) {
        $newArray["{$letter}{$number}"] = $value; // cria novamente o array ordenado por letras e numeros
    }
}
```

#### Out

```
Array
(
    [A1] => A1
    [A2] => A2
    [A4] => A4
    [A5] => A5
    [A10] => A10
    [A11] => A11
    [A12] => A12
    [B7] => B7
    [B12] => B12
    [C1] => C1
    [C5] => C5
    [C12] => C12
    [C52] => C52
)
```

#### OBS

Pode haver falhas caso a chave seja composta de letras e números e estes estejam misturados. Ex.: `A12C8`.

Comment: Verificarei assim que possível, Guilherme. Quanto a composição da chave, é somente um valor mesmo de A1-A99 até Z1-Z99, então não há caso em que se misturem.