# Sql - Ordenação Natural - Varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql, classificação

#### Situação

Necessito realizar a ordenação Natural da string.

#### Exemplo

```
Processo 1
Processo 2
Processo 3
Processo 10
Processo 11
Processo 12
```

#### Order Padrão. (ASC)

```
Processo 1
Processo 10
Processo 11
Processo 12
Processo 2
Processo 3
```

#### Order Natural

```
Processo 1
Processo 2
Processo 3
Processo 10
Processo 11
Processo 12
```

#### Relacionado

[PHP Ordenacao natural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/ordenar-array-por-chave-sendo-uma-string/91394#answer-91401)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução que encontrei no SO foi [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173558/postgresql-order-by-issue-natural-sort)

#### Codigo

```
ORDER BY 
    regexp_replace(column_name, '\D','','g')::integer
```

#### Explicação

Ele ira remover da string tudo que não seja numero, então converter para inteiro, apos aplicar a ordenação com base nos inteiro.

[Exemplo ordenação padrão](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/95e77/5)
[Exemplo ordenação natural](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/95e77/4)

Comment: Se funcionar, cria um fiddle com um exemplo testavel :)

Comment: @rray Consegui por o exemplo = D

Comment: Depois de 262728256 tentativas xD sqlfiddle é complicado.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    column_name 
FROM 
    table_name 
ORDER BY
    column_name REGEXP '^\d*[^\da-z&\.\' \-\"\!\@\#\$\%\^\*\(\)\;\:\\,\?\/\~\`\|\_\-]' DESC, 
    column_name + 0, 
    column_name;
```